# Inserção de caractere especial no final de página e quando clico no botão Código-Fonte no CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

Por favor. Foi instalado o Ckeditor 4.17 numa página web / html com PHP 7.3. Meu banco, backend e html está com utf-8 e estou com o seguinte problema: Quando clico no botão Código-Fonte do próprio editor do CKEditor ou no botão Salvar é inserido um caractere especial Â no final do texto quando tem espaço na exibição do texto rich text. Reparei que isto só ocorre quando deixa múltiplos espaços com enter no final do arquivo / texto escrito. Agradeço pela ajuda e fico no aguardo.

Tentei achar configurações no próprio CKEDITOR.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Acabei removendo o caractere Â de todo o código fonte js do Ckeditor 4.17  e acabou funcionando.